# How to show image based on an object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a variable with four keys. When the icon key has the value 01d, I need to display the icon referring to this value, which is in the img folder. How can I make this conditional?

I have the following variable destructuring and below I put its return.

`let [dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4, dt5, dt6, dt7, dt8] = urlJson` returns:

```
{ dt: 1643803200, day: 12.84, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' }
{ dt: 1643889600, day: 14.56, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1643976000, day: 14.85, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644062400, day: 14.41, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644148800, day: 14.99, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' }
{ dt: 1644235200, day: 15.68, description: 'few clouds', icon: '02d' }
{ dt: 1644321600, day: 14.95, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' }
{ dt: 1644408000, day: 16.37, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link id="mystylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 class="city"></h1>
    <h2><span id="tags">0</span>ºC</h2>
  </div>
  <script>
    const urlJsonString = $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=38.7267&lon=-9.1403&exclude=current,hourly,minutely,alerts&units=metric&appid={APPID}', function (data) {
      let urlJson = data.daily.map(({ dt, temp: { day }, weather: [{ description, icon }] }) => ({ dt, day, description, icon }))
      let [dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4, dt5, dt6, dt7, dt8] = urlJson
      var date = dt1.dt

      let result = `Temperature: ${dt1.day} ºC<br>
      Dia: ${date}<br>
      ${dt1.icon}`
      $(".city").html(result);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `urlJsonString` and `urlJson` are terrible names for these variables because they do not contain anything related to their current names.

Comment: And where's the connection between the title and _"I need to display the icon referring to this value ... How can I make this conditional?"_ ?

Comment: Also looks like `urlJson` and `[dt1,dt2....` and `date` and 'result' can all be marked `const`

Comment: @Andreas not to mention he has 8 dates listed in code, but title says 7

Comment: you basically just want to replace `${dt1.icon}` with `<image src='...' />`

Comment: I need to refer the image to the icon key value. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm not experienced like you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works to you. I have no key access to this API, so i've made with your fictional data.

Please be sure that your 'icon' is your image URL

https://jsfiddle.net/ep9hsxLf/

```js
let urlJson = [
  { dt: 1643803200, day: 12.84, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' },
  { dt: 1643889600, day: 14.56, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' },
  { dt: 1643976000, day: 14.85, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' },
  { dt: 1644062400, day: 14.41, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' },
  { dt: 1644148800, day: 14.99, description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' },
  { dt: 1644235200, day: 15.68, description: 'few clouds', icon: '02d' },
  { dt: 1644321600, day: 14.95, description: 'broken clouds', icon: '04d' },
  { dt: 1644408000, day: 16.37, description: 'overcast clouds', icon: '04d' }
]

var htmlResult = '';

urlJson.forEach(item => {

  var date = new Date(item.dt)

  htmlResult += `Temperature: ${item.day} ºC<br>
  Dia: ${date}<br>
  ${item.icon}<br><br>`
});


$(".city").html(htmlResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city"></div>
```